# netbeans project sharing

Tags: java, netbeans

I have developed a GUI application in NetBeans and I want to share it with my friend. I just created a RAR archive of the entire project folder and sent him. He extracted the contents and opened in his IDE, but he gets the following errors..

He said that cannot find main method is the error being thrown
(java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: ssdsimulation/SSDSimulator : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0)

Comment: Note: For sharing projects I recommend using a version control system, e.g. Mercurial.

Comment: It's not really a solution for your problem, but I suggest to use [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) if you develop a java project together with others, because this project can be opened with almost any IDE out there.

Comment: And yes, as @Puce mentioned, a VCS is also a good idea. But I prefer git to mercurial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He needs to install and use Java SE 7.

Comment: oh.. okay, I almost forgot to mention that I developed using Java 7. Thanks for the hint. I'll tell him to do that.